# Monospace font is ignored in xml layout for Honor 10i

Tags: android, fonts, huawei-developers

I have simple layout with a TextView and want to use a monospace font, but on Honor 10i it is not works. I used "device explorer" and find all system fonts in the device. Any hints?

```
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="99"
        android:textSize="96dp"
        android:fontFamily="monospace"
        android:typeface="monospace"
        android:includeFontPadding="false"
        />
```